# C#. Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Вопрос, наверняка, окажется глупым и не носящем практической ценности, но тем не менее. Сейчас вплотную разбираюсь с многопоточностью и параллельным программированием. На всех ресурсах пишут приблизительно следующее.
"Приложение запускается всегда в приоритетном потоке...." и 
"При завершении всех приоритетных потоков, все фоновые также завершаются, даже, если не выполнили свои задачи". 
Отсюда сабж, почему приложение не завершается, когда явно указывается

```
Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
```

?

Просьба помочь разобраться. 
И прицепом еще один. В чем практическое отличие

```
Task task = new Task(MyTask);
```

от

```
Thread tr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyTask));
```

?

я так понял, Задачи в целом эффективнее распределяются за счет планировщика задач

Comment: 1) А чего вдруг должен завершаться основной поток приложения. Он делает работу до тех, пока ему не скажут это прекратить и является основным 2) Thread - поток, а Task - *абстракция* "кусочек работы", которые соединяются в цепочку. Это вообще разные понятия и связывает их только то, что получившаяся цепочка (или единственная задача) перемалываются *дефолтным* планировщиком через пул потоков, а то и без него.

Comment: Мысль строилась на том, что раз мы единственный приоритетный поток делаем фоновым, значит приоритетных больше нет, а значит следует, что приложение должно закрыться. Поэтому и пытаюсь понять весь механизм. Для чего тогда нужно это свойство? Или тут свои тонкости, касаемо основного потока. По задачам понял, спасибо.

Comment: Это просто метка. Основной поток приложения - тоже поток и потому ему тоже можно дать эту метку. Само наличие метки не делает ничего. да, тут тонкости касаемо основного потока.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По первой части вопроса, думаю, это пробел в документации. В документации говорится, что происходит при *завершении* основного, нефонового потока, но ничего не говорится о случае, когда поток просто прекращает быть основным, не завершаясь при этом. Я не нашёл ссылок на это ни в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx), ни в [спецификации языка](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#application-termination).

---

По поводу второй части вопроса:

Thread — это физический (кроме очень крайних частных случаев) поток выполнения, имеющий прямое соответствие с потоками операционной системы. Task — абстракция задания, которое будет когда-либо выполнено, и соответствующий заданию код может бежать в одном или нескольких, иногда даже в нулевом количестве потоков.

Для случая использования, который вы привели, разница в *эффекте* незначительна: Task в том виде, в котором  он вызывается в вашем с коде из вопроса, выполняется на потоке из пула потоков, а Thread создаётся вне пула. Но есть разница в *использовании*.

Для Thread'а вы можете лишь вызвать `Join`, и синхронно дождаться его завершения.

Для Task вы можете, кроме того, установить *продолжение* посредством `ContinueWith`, которое будет выполнено в будущем, по завершению этого Task'а. Кроме того, вы можете дождаться о окончания Task'а *асинхронно*, используя `await`. Вы можете снаружи поймать и обработать исключение, произошедшее при выполнении Task'а. Всё это с Thread'ом недоступно.

Comment: `Thread — это физический (кроме очень крайних частных случаев)`, а можно пример?

Comment: @Aarnihauta: Можно. SQL Server 2.0 пытался вместо нативных thread'ов использовать fiber'ы (https://stackoverflow.com/q/18436409/276994, http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/11/09/fibers-and-the-clr/), а вообще за thread'ы отвечает CLR host, и вы можете используя кастомный хост поставить в соответствие thread'ам что угодно (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476711/276994, https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md),